# TFS 2013 WI History Discussion clogged with TFSBuild entries

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-workitem

Using TFS 2013, we don't seem to be able to use the History section for Work Items because it just gets clogged full of the following statements:

TFSBuild (2 days ago)

The Fixed In field was updated as part of associating work items with the build.

This is where I assume we're supposed to write history such as "tested the bug, re-opening since the following error is still occurring...". We've been putting all comments like this in the Description field though because they get lost in the history section with all the Fixed In messages.

It seems like every single build produces this Fixed In message, although it might be limited to the product backlog item - it doesn't seem consistent. Some items have about 50 of these entries and some have none.

My expectation was that these messages would only show up on the work items that the programmers referred to when committing the code. Are they possibly doing something strange when committing the code? Or is there some sort of procedure I can do to stop these messages from filling up the history entry? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set "Associate Changesets and Work Items" option to "False" in your build definition to stop updating the associate work items when a build is completed.

Work items will be updated when the build with associated changeset completes and "Associate Changesets and Work Items" is set to "True". Your problem looks the same as this question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/40028/tfs-stop-team-build-process-has-updated-the-fixed-in-field-messages. 
It was caused by the build wasn't completely succeed. You can refer to it to see if it can help you resolve the problem.

For more detailed information about Associate Changesets and Work Items, you can read this blog:
http://www.andygeldman.com/index.php/2011/10/ever-expanding-associated-changesets-and-work-items/comment-page-1/